# Ngrx Selectors: createSelector VS pure rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

Hi great internet minds,

I'm trying to understand advanced uses for ngrx selectors and working on digesting this article: [ngrx selectors](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md)

There are examples showing createSelctors and some of pure rxjs magic. Is any advantage to using one vs another. The method of interests are getAllActiveUsersNGRX VS getAllActiveUsersRXJS.

Sample

```javascript
const selectUserStore = (state: GlobalState) => state.userStore;

const getAllUsers = createSelector(
    selectUserStore ,
    (state: UserState) => state.allUsers
);

const getAllActiveUsersNGRX = createSelector(
    getAllUsers,
    (users: IUser[]) => users.filter(user => (user.active === true))
);

const getAllActiveUsersRXJS = pipe(
    select(getAllUsers),
    map((users: IUser[]) => users.filter(user=> (user.active === true)))
);
```

I know using them with the store is going to be different also

E.g

```javascript
store.pipe(select(getAllActiveUsersNGRX));
```

VS

```javascript
store.pipe(select(getAllActiveUsersRXJS));
```

Aside from the way they are used with the store, are there some benefits I have yet to understand or is it purely coding preference?

Thanks

Comment: https://netbasal.com/lets-talk-about-select-and-reselect-in-ngrx-store-177a2f6045a8

Comment: Thanks Cartant. I don't think I fully understand the article. My take away is createSelector's benefit will shine when using it to combine multiple pieces of state to optimize the store's subscription? In the examble above, given it only extracts just a single piece of state from the store, is it safe to assume they are then identical?

Comment: Yeah, that's my understanding. `createSelector` can be called to combine multiple slices of state - by passing multiple selectors - and it's when that's done that behaviour differs (and is more efficient). You're not doing that, so there should be no difference.

Comment: Super thanks!!! Read over the article a few more times and I think that makes sense. It seems it is a great addition to entity also. Given that entity usually stores multiple data sets per entity (obj + array), then having a subscription fire 2x per change will get annoying fast.

Comment: You should promote that to an answer so we can check it off

Comment: I've used `reselect`, but I've not used the most recent version of NgRx. I'll leave the answer for someone who's more up-to-date than me.

Comment: Sounds good! Really appreciate the lead

Answer (score 4):

From outside they are the same. The difference is how often `(users: IUser[]) => users.filter(user => (user.active === true))` function will be called.
As `createSelector` create memoized function.

> The selector function returned by calling createSelector or
>   createFeatureSelector initially has a memoized value of null. After a
>   selector is invoked the first time its memoized value is stored in
>   memory. If the selector is subsequently invoked with the same
>   arguments it will return the memoized value. If the selector is then
>   invoked with different arguments it will recompute and update its
>   memoized value

[ngRx docs](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md)